# Merge sequential filename repetitions in list

Tags: python, data-structures

I've been trying to create a script that loops through and merges CSVs in a folder and calculates the averages of specific columns and exports the results to a single file. So far I've managed to create the logic for it now but I'm struggling with the identification for each column in the resulting CSV, these columns should be named after the 3 files that were averaged.
I've listed the files in the current directory using `glob`, all the files are named with the pattern:

`AA_XXXX-b`.

Where `AA` is a sample number and `b` is the repetition (1-2 for duplicates, 1-3 for triplicates, etc.) and `XXXX` is a short sample description. I thought of using the list generated when listing the files and somehow merge all repetitions of a sample into a single item with a format like:

`AA_XXXX_1-N`,

Where N is the number of repetitions, and store the merged names in a list in order to use it to name the columns with the averages in the final file, but couldn't think of or find anything similar. I apologize if this question was already asked.

Edit:

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:
This is what the data in the individual csvs looks like:

| Filename: 01_NoCons-1 | abs |
| --- | --- |
| Wavelength (nm) | 0 |
| 901.5391 | 0.523718 |
| 902.8409 | 0.516127 |
| 905.4431 | 0.521074 |
| 908.0434 | 0.516442 |
| 909.3429 | 0.510993 |

| Filename: 01_NoCons-2 | abs |
| --- | --- |
| Wavelength (nm) | 0 |
| 901.5391 | 0.523718 |
| 902.8409 | 0.516127 |
| 905.4431 | 0.521074 |
| 908.0434 | 0.516442 |
| 909.3429 | 0.510993 |

| Filename: 01_NoCons- 3 | abs |
| --- | --- |
| Wavelength (nm) | 0 |
| 901.5391 | 0.523718 |
| 902.8409 | 0.516127 |
| 905.4431 | 0.521074 |
| 908.0434 | 0.516442 |
| 909.3429 | 0.510993 |

And after concatenating and calculating the average of the 3 `abs` columns, the result is transfered to a new table already containing the `Wavelenght` column like so:

| Filename: Final table | 01_NoCons_1-3 |
| --- | --- |
| Wavelength (nm) | 0 |
| 901.5391 | 0.523718 |
| 902.8409 | 0.516127 |
| 905.4431 | 0.521074 |
| 908.0434 | 0.516442 |
| 909.3429 | 0.510993 |

This process is repeated for every set of sample repetitions, and I'd like the resulting column name to identify from which set it was generated, such as `01_NoCons_1-3`, which indicates that the column is a result of the average of repetitions 1 to 3 of the sample `01_NoCons`

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to do, just by reading your descrition. Could you please include an example of the contents of the files (perhaps limiting to 3 files and 5 rows per file, as we don't need to full files to understand).

Comment: Sure, I'll include more information in the description